# Output keeps referencing a place in memory whenever i compile (Java)

Tags: java, memory, reference

Every time I compile my code in Netbeans I keep getting this as output:

> com.logger.ErrorFrequency@1357842

And I don't have any idea what it is or how to make the code give me the expected result. I have googled all to no avail and checked my code. but I don't see anything wrong with it.

This is my code:

```
package com.logger;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestA {
    static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monitor";

    final String error;
    final Date sta;

    //initialize constructor
    public TestA(){
        super();
        this.error = null;
        this.sta = null;
    }
    public TestA(String p, Date n) {
        error = p;
        sta = n;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return error + ", " + sta;
    }

    public String getReport(){
        return error;
    }
    public Date getSta(){
        return sta;
    }


    public List getErrDesc(){
        //String data = null;
        Date date = null;
        List<TestA> list = new ArrayList<TestA>();
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT error_description, error_date     FROM error_log WHERE service_source = 'Billbox' ");

            while (result.next()) {  //retrieve data

                String ds = result.getString("error_date");
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("y/M/d h:m:s a").parse(ds);
                TestA es = new TestA(result.getString("error_description"), date);
                list.add(es);

                //System.out.println(data);
            }
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LogDB.class.getName()).log( 
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return list;
  }   
}
```

Then this is for the second class:

```
package com.logger;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

class ErrorFrequency  {
    private final List errStamp;


    public ErrorFrequency(List ae) {
        errStamp = ae;

    }

    public List getReport(){
        return errStamp;
    }



    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<ErrorFrequency> pq = new PriorityQueue<ErrorFrequency>();

        TestA element = new TestA();
        List item = element.getErrDesc();
        ErrorFrequency e = new ErrorFrequency(item);

        pq.add(e);
        ErrorFrequency peek = pq.peek();
        System.out.println(peek.toString());
        System.out.println(pq.size());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `peek.toString()` needs to be overridden if you want to use it for output.

The default `toString()` method shows the object class and its hash code so that you can tell different object instances apart.

> com.logger.ErrorFrequency@1357842

Is actually

> class@hashcode

What you can do to print out your report is this:

```
for(Object o: peek.getReport()) {
    // Do stuff with your object here.
    // I don't know what type your list
    // If it is a list of strings you can use this:
    System.out.println((String)o);
}
```

Comment: I just tried it. it threw an exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.logger.TestA cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Besides that, where you referring to Object o when you said do stuff with your object here? Also, it is not a list of Strings